# Radeon black screen on Ubuntu 16.10 Linux 4.8

Tags: radeon, 16.10

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.10 (Linux 4.8). After the upgrade, my screen turns and stays black on booting.

I tried the advanced option to run Ubuntu 16.10 on Linux kernel 4.4 and it works.

I know that fglrx is no longer supported since Ubuntu 16.04, so Ubuntu has been using the open source version (xserver-xorg-video-radeon).

My question is that how can it work in Linux 4.4 but not 4.8 (both are Ubuntu 16.10)? and how to solve the issues to make it work on Linux 4.8?

Thank you

**Edit 1:**

This question is **not duplicate** as indicated by many. In my case, I can boot on Linux kernel 4.4, but not 4.8.

Comment: What GPU do you have? Please post the output of `lspci -nnnk`.

Comment: Sorry, it has been a while. I have solved the issue by installing fglrx-pxpress. Thanks.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it once the question has been reopened. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Comment: Thanks David, I have posted it. Now I now how to use this platform :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have **solved** the issue by installing fglrx-pxpress. The description of the package is:

"This is a transitional package for ubuntu drivers-common. You can remove it after upgrading."

However, I still need the package even after upgrading.